# Why does interface pages in java documentation have method summary ?

Tags: java, nio

Is a class(for eg: **A**) internally defined which implements the interface ? Does  the method summary  shown in  interface pages of Java Documentation is actually  the 
implementation done by the class **A** whose implementation is hidden from us ?

For Example :

```
interface Path { void help();}
class PathImpl implements Path {
  String path;
  PathImpl(String path) { this.path = path; }
  void help(){ System.out.println("Help");}
}
```

The Path interface  documentation has method summary . Is there a hidden class PathImpl which implements every method in Path ? Is the method summary shown in online documentation actually the method implementations done in PathImpl which is hidden from us ?

Answer (score 0):

It just shows the interface of its methods, which every implementer class should follow. For example, if you look at the javadoc for java.util.List, you will see how every method is used, but you don't see the actual implemention, which is left to each implementer class as ArrayList, as far as it respect the interface of List.

Comment: But how can List have method implementations , it is interface ,right ?

Comment: Exactly, you will find the implementations in the implementing classes such as ArrayList. In the interface you just find the definition of the method (name, signature,return type, exceptions thrown), but you don't fine the implementation.

Comment: @BacterioVevo In Java 8, interfaces can have implementations.

Comment: @PeterLawrey https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html       so all the methods present here are default methods ?

Comment: @BacterioVevo yes, many interfaces have default, and some have static method.  Interfaces can't have fields.

Comment: Default methods have the default keyword modifier. So for the Path class there are no default methods. Infact you don't find the default tab in the javadoc

Comment: For a default method example, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html

Comment: @Peter Lawrey interfaces can have public static final fields, i.e. constants

Comment: @chess4ever true, but not instance fields. Note: static final fields could be mutable. e.g. `List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();` Not a good idea, but possible.

Comment: Path  p1  = Paths.get("C:\\Java_Dev\\test1.txt"); 
     Path  p2  = Paths.get("C:\\Java_Dev\\LUCI1.TXT");
     boolean b1  = p1.equals(p2);
  
   
       In the following code , how can we create an interface object and where is the method equals() implemented , as it cannot be implemented in interface ?

Comment: Your are not creating an interface object because by definition interface cannot be instantiated. What is happening is the the get method will instantiate class X which implements interface Path and will return it as a Path object. The equals method is implemented in the X class. The point of using an interface type as the type of variables p1 and p2 is to allow polymorphism (look here for more about it in the context of the java language https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Comment: The point is that there may exist many different types of path objects which provide different implementation, but you don't want to take care of it, so you just want to know what the interface provides.

Comment: One advantage of this is that the implementer could change the internal implementation without no concerns, as far as the interface is still implemented.